# PayPal Pro - PayFlow: setExpressCheckout API call returns "Not signed up for this tender type"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I am using Express Checkout with Payflow Gateway on a test account.

I try to send a setExpressCheckout call to start the Express Checkout basic integration, following the guide in [Payflow/Express-Checkout - SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/express-checkout/sale/#setexpresscheckout).

The response I get is:

> [RESULT] => 25 [RESPMSG] => Not signed up for this tender type.

After checking the meaning of this error I found there are 3 options why I get result code 25:

- Card type not on account
- Original transaction ID not valid
- Empty Credit Card field

I am not passing credit card data or original transaction ID (not ones of setExpressCheckout call), So 3 of them did not help...

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Payflow support to enable the PayPal tender type for the account.